# Cannot open view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Good day. I recently learn about laravel. Then, i'm trying to fetch data from database (I'm using Sqlsrv) But i face an error

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
>   (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\boby\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)

Here is my script

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $datauser = DB::table('users')->get();
    return view('welcome',compact('datauser'));
});
```

and my view is like this (like welcome.blade.php)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <style>
            html, body {
                background-color: #fff;
                color: #636b6f;
                font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
                font-weight: 100;
                height: 100vh;
                margin: 0;
            }

            .full-height {
                height: 100vh;
            }

            .flex-center {
                align-items: center;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
            }

            .position-ref {
                position: relative;
            }

            .top-right {
                position: absolute;
                right: 10px;
                top: 18px;
            }

            .content {
                text-align: center;
            }

            .title {
                font-size: 84px;
            }

            .links > a {
                color: #636b6f;
                padding: 0 25px;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-weight: 600;
                letter-spacing: .1rem;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }

            .m-b-md {
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            @foreach ($datauser as $user)
                <li> {{ $user }} </li>>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

how can handle this error ? thanks in advance

Comment: you can't print an object as string, even if it has only one value. You can do it like Sandeesh explained it or you print it as a json object `{{ json_encode($user) }}` if you don't know all values of your object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't display an object like that. You need to fetch the properties when displaying.

```
<li> {{ $user->id }} </li>>
<li> {{ $user->name }} </li>>
<li> {{ $user->email }} </li>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `{{}}` to display object.
in the `foreach` , `$user` is an object , 
if you want to show user's email, use it `{{ $user->email }}`